# Android layouts based on aspect ratio?

Tags: android, aspect-ratio

This is a bit hard to explain, so I'll try with an example.

Let's say I've got a 3:2 image, that it'd like in one of my applications. I'd like the width of the `ImageView` to match its parent (`match_parent`), and I'd like the height to scale according to the aspect ratio of the image and the width of the image.

How is that possible in Android? I'd really like to know if there's a better way than creating pre-defined sizes for all kinds of different screen resizes.

Another scenario could be a grid view with lots of items - it'd be great if I could just tell Android how many items it should show in each row and what aspect ratio these items should have. It'd make things so much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution is to simply set a `layout_width` and `layout_height` and then set the `android:scaleType` to `centerCrop`. It's far from perfect, but works OK, and you can get some fairly decent results if you use `auto_fit` with a `GridView`.

Answer (score 0):

What about the scaling parameters for the ImageView? Probably something like this:

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:scaleType="whatever you want"
/>
```

Comment: So I don't think that what you're looking for exists. When I needed to set some images in a GridView to be the same width and height, I ended up doing that programmatically in the adapter for the GridView. If you want to use a GridView, then you can programmatically tell it what the number of columns should be and then specify the widths and heights of your images in the getView method of the adapter. It's ugly, but what're you gonna do!